# Proving Lipschitz (or not)

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, lipschitz-functions

Consider a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ and an arbitrary vector $u \in  \mathbb{R}^n$. Is
$$f(x) = \log(1+e^{u^Tx})$$
Lipschitz? In other words, can we prove -
$$\exists L,\ ||y-x|| \leq L |f(y)-f(x)| \ \forall x,y$$

I have been staring at this problem for an hour but do not know how to solve it! In particular, I don't know what to do after writing $\log(\frac{1+e^{u^Ty}}{1+e^{u^Tx}})$.
Any help/hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to check that the derivative $Df$ is bounded in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Notice that $Df(x)=\dfrac{e^{u^Tx}u}{1+e^{u^Tx}}$, so that $\| Df(x)\|\leq \| u\|$, where $\| \cdot\|$ denotes the Euclidean norm in $\mathbb{R}^n$.